# Guava jar (Google core library) used for ObjectArray, prints a lot of messages on log4j

Tags: java, log4j, guava

I am using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) libraries for concatenation of objectarrays like this

```
import com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays ;
....
plannedList = ObjectArrays.concat(plannedList, newPlannedList, Object.class);
```

But on my system log I get a lot messages. I wonder if this jar is doing more than just what I need. Do I really need all these resourcepools to be allocated, checked and what not ?

I know I can figure out a way to mask all this using log4j properties, but before I do that I just want to be sure.

> > 05 May 2013 11:19:13,831 7621066 [Timer-0] DEBUG BasicResourcePool  - BEGIN check for expired resources.  [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@15f7107]
> >     05 May 2013 11:19:13,831 7621066 [Timer-0] DEBUG BasicResourcePool  - FINISHED check for expired resources.  [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@15f7107]
> >
> > java.lang.Exception: DEBUG -- CLOSE BY CLIENT STACK TRACE
> >         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:491)
> >         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:191)
> >         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:470)
> >         at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:964)
> >         at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
> >     05 May 2013 11:14:13,832 7321067 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0] DEBUG C3P0PooledConnectionPool  - Successfully destroyed PooledConnection: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@93b72e
> >     05 May 2013 11:14:13,832 7321067 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0] DEBUG BasicResourcePool  - Successfully destroyed resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@93b72e
> >     05 May 2013 11:14:43,829 7351064 [Timer-0] DEBUG BasicResourcePool  - Checking for expired resources - Sun May 05 11:14:43 UTC 2013 [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@15f7107]
> >
> > 05 May 2013 11:14:13,830 7321065 [Timer-0] DEBUG BasicResourcePool  - Removing expired resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@93b72e [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@15f7107]
> >     05 May 2013 11:14:13,830 7321065 [Timer-0] DEBUG BasicResourcePool  - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@15f7107 [managed: 4, unused: 1, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@9444d1)
> >     05 May 2013 11:14:13,830 7321065 [Timer-0] DEBUG BasicResourcePool  - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@15f7107 [managed: 4, unused: 1, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@9444d1)
> >     05 May 2013 11:14:13,830 7321065 [Timer-0] DEBUG BasicResourcePool  - EXPIRED idle resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@1df6be0 ---> idle_time: 141673; max_idle_time: 120000 [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@15f7107]
> >     05 May 2013 11:14:13,830 7321065 [Timer-0] DEBUG BasicResourcePool  - Removing expired resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@1df6be0 [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@15f7107]
> >     05 May 2013 11:14:13,830 7321065 [Timer-0] DEBUG BasicResourcePool  - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@15f7107 [managed: 3, unused: 0, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@9444d1)
> >     05 May 2013 11:14:13,830 7321065 [Timer-0] DEBUG BasicResourcePool  - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@15f7107 [managed: 3, unused: 0, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@9444d1)
> >     05 May 2013 11:14:13,830 7321065 [Timer-0] DEBUG BasicResourcePool  - FINISHED check for expired resources.  [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@15f7107]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your logs, I can't see any `com.google`, so I'd bet they have nothing to do with Guava. In fact, there's only `com.mchange`, which has nothing to do with Guava (you might be using it because of Hibernate or alike). Try to grep your sources, configuration and/or libraries for it.